# Looping though list of IDs to count matches in two columns

Tags: linux, awk

This is going to be a complicated one to explain so bear with me.

I am doing a blastp comparison multiple proteins all vs all and want the number of shared proteins between the genomes.

I have a large file of the query id and sequence id, example:

```
A       A       100
A       A       100
A       A       100
A       B       74
A       B       47
A       B       67
A       C       73
A       C       84
A       C       74
A       D       48
A       D       74
A       D       74
B       A       67
B       A       83
B       A       44
B       B       100
```

The file continues like that. I'd like to count the number of occurrences of A in column 1 and B in column 2. I have found a way to do this with awk:

```
awk -F, '$1=="A" && $2=="A"' file | wc -l
```

However, I have hundreds of genomes and this would involve typing the awk script thousands of times to get the different combinations. I had added the IDs from column 1 to a text file and tried a loop to loop through all the IDs for all possible combinations

```
for i in $(cat ID.txt); do input_file=file.csv; awk -F, '$1==$i && $2==$i' ${input_file} | wc -l; done
```

This is the output:

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

etc.

I'd like the output to be:

```
A       A       60
A       B       54
A       C       34
A       D       35
```

etc.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's your field separator? Multiple spaces or one tab?

Comment: The field separator is a tab

Comment: so you want to ignore all rows that don't have an `A` in the 1st column? if you want to count all rows (eg, including rows with a `B` in the 1st column) then please update the question to show the expected output corresponding with the sample input

Comment: please explain how you obtained `A A 60` from `A A 100` / `A A 100` / `A A 100` ... ???

Comment: That number is the shared protein count. The numbers in the third column aren't really important. It was used for an example. I want to count the occurrences of A in column 1 and A in column 2, then A in column 1 and B in column 2. Does that make sense?

Comment: again, please update the question to show the expected output that matches the sample intput you've provided; we should be able to take your sample input and generate the expected output; it appears (to me) that your expected output is based on your actual data file but since we don't have access to your actual data file there is no way we'll ever be able to generate your expected output ... so we're left guessing at what you want and/or if our answers are correct; based solely on your comments and (incorrect) expected output we are to ignore any rows where the 1st column != `A`, right?

Comment: You say `The field separator is a tab` but in your code you set it to a comma (`awk -F, ...`) and tell us that works - which is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, then you can collect the count for each pair into an array, and then print out the array once complete:

```
 awk -F, '{++a[$1 FS $2]} END{for(entry in a){print entry, a[entry]}}' file
```

---

```
A,A 3
B,A 3
A,B 3
B,B 1
A,C 3
A,D 3
```

This is doing the following:

1. Increment the count in array `a` for the item with the key constructed from the concatenation of the first two columns, separated by the field separator `FS` (comma):  `{++a[$1 FS $2]}`
2. Once the file processing is done `END`, loop through the array calling each array entry `entry`, `for (entry in a)`
3. In the loop, print the key/entry and the value `{print entry, a[entry]}`

Comment: Yes you've understood that correctly. Is there a way to add a space between the letters in the first column? My ID names are quite long

Comment: You can just add a space character in the array key: `++a[$1" "$2]`

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Answer (score -1):

```
…input… | WHINY_USERS=1 \   # Not trying to insult anyone - 
                            # this is a special shell parameter 
                            # recognized by mawk-1 to have array 
                            # indices pre-sorted, somewhat similar to gawk's
                            #
                            # PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"

mawk '{__[$!--NF]—-} END { for(_ in __) { print _,-__[_] } }' OFS=',' FS='[, \t]+' 

A,A,3
A,B,3
A,C,3
A,D,3
B,A,3
B,B,1
```

if there's a chance more in than 3 columns in input, then do :

```
{m,n,g}awk '

BEGIN { _ += _ ^= FS = "["(OFS=",")" \t]+"
}     { __[$!(NF=_)]++
} END { 
        for(_ in __) { print _, __[_] } }'
```

let `$1 = $1` take care of placing the comma in between columns 1 and 2 instead of having to manually do it